# Having issues setting font size in PoDoFo

Tags: pdf, c++

We seem to have a problem with SetFontSize, no matter what size we set, we still get the default size.

[This post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54513975/117259) reports a similar issue.

Is there a workaround or known solution for this problem?

Comment: I'm currently getting the same behavior. The other stackoverflow post you provided updated its answer and states that his "dll was weird" and it worked after exchanging it... However the problem seems to be platform independent...

Comment: Update: Do you use the font in two different font sizes in your PdfPage? Creating another `PdfFont` and specifying a different font using another font size seems to work - with various side effects...

Comment: Hmm okay. No, I have just used the one, have to try using a second one then. My workaround at the moment is to set the transformation matrix and scale the text, it got the desired result.

Comment: I had a similar issue and found a fix to it. You can read the [discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/podofo/mailman/podofo-users/thread/LO2P123MB382335A3F74659BFECF274A1C1259%40LO2P123MB3823.GBRP123.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM/#msg37289554) I had with the PoDoFo team which has some other useful suggestions in case my fix doesn't work for you.